# Django REST Swagger HTTPS requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger-2.0, django-rest-swagger

How configure [django-rest-swagger](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get a HTTPS requests?

upd:
SSL cert is present and ALL app working with it, but swagger make a http requests.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this setting in your `settings.py`,

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

For more details, refer [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header)..

Also, you may need to make sure your server is forwarding `x_forwarded_proto` and on nginx add this to your location within server config:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;
```

Comment: its not help for me

Comment: Did you add the settings in your nginx config file?

Comment: sure, i add settings in my nginx conf.

Comment: Could you show the relevant piece of code you've added?

Comment: Any apache specific settings?  I have a "redirect permanent / https://localhost.my.org/"

Answer (score 2):

Put url='https://your_server_address/', in get_schema_view function in urls.

But swagger now only works on https, if you want to work on both http and https you can handle this through env variables.

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions didn't work for me, so i did something **HORRIBLE** that worked:

Edited drf_yasg/**openapi.py** Line 260

From:

```
self.schemes = [url.scheme]
```

To:

```
self.schemes = ["https"]
```

Obviously you **should not do this** because the next time someone installs requirements this change will be lost. But it helped me to get the documentation working on my server.

Answer (score -1):

@zaidfazil's answer almost worked for me. I had to add

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

to my django settings but then I had to add

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

instead of:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;
```

inside nginx's location block that serves the django app.

Answer (score -4):

That's not an issue with your swagger. Just install an SSL cert on your django-serving app server.

Comment: SSL cert is present and  ALL app working with it, but swagger make a http requests.